# Vectorization of recursively defined problem - Python

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, vectorization

I was wondering if anyone would have an idea on how I am able to vectorize the following loop:

```
for i in range(1,(T*n)+1):
    Y = Y + np.diag(mu) @ Y * dt + np.multiply(np.diag(sigma)@Y, L @ np.random.normal( 0, dt, (d,N)))
```

Whereas the following parameters are already a dxN matrices (I already vectorized a loop with that..):

- Y *(this is the recursive Parameter)*
- np.diag(mu) @ Y  * dt
- np.diag(sigma) @ Y
- L @ np.random.normal( 0, dt, (d,N))

Any help would be very appreciated. :)

With best regards!

Comment: One instant saving I would suggest is replacing `diag(x) @ y` with `x[:, None] * y` (I'm assuming `x` is a vector)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I am pretty new to python and x (or resp. mu) is a array hence defined as e.g. mu = [0.05, 0.06, 0.09, ... ,0.05]. Python gives me the following error message: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". Can you help me to fix that please?

Comment: Just covert to `array` first: `mu = np.array(mu)`

Comment: Hey PaulPanzer. I converted it and it worked. Sadly this made the processing actually slower.. from ~86secounds to about ~90seconds.

Comment: Oops! How long (number of elements) are these vectors? Just curious.

Comment: mu and sigma are 1x10 and Y is 10x10000

Comment: Funny, when I directly compare `a[:, None] * b` and `np.diag(a) @ b` for `a.shape = (10,)` and `b.shape = (10, 10000)` the first is three times as fast for me.

Comment: Thats super wired. Maybe it is related to using np.multiply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't look like vectorizable code:

1. Iterations should be independent. Typically, vectorization means making several iterations at once. Typically, it also implies using AVX, SSE or FMA instructions (if we talk about x86 processors) to make iterations go truly in parallel on a hardware level.
2. Continuing about vector assembly instructions, such level of optimization is typically unreachable from python code because the interpreter isn't *that* smart. An iteration is also doing too much to be vectorized. It actually contains sub-loops! We don't see it but matrix multiplications do involve more loops.

So I woudn't call optimization of this loop a "vectorization". But luckily, there are still things to check:

1. Profile it. Find out what part of the computation consumes most of the time.
2. Verify that `np.random` doesn't slow down the program significantly. If yes, you can rely on pre-generated values instead.
3. Check if code that can be vectorized *is* vectorized. That means, verify that your numpy is built with SSE/AVX support and that matrix multiplications use that under the hood. It can be a bit tricky to do but up to x4 speedups* are possible with AVX usage.
4. If parts of the code are indeed vectorized on the assembly level, switching to storing data in float16 arrays can make it even faster. To my knowledge, AVX does support operations on large blocks of 16-bit floats.
5. Rewrite it in C/Cython or try out Numba JIT compilation for the same task.
6. If compilation even with Numba is not the case, I wonder if Tensorflow can help here. With Tensorflow, Python code doesn't kick off computations immediately but rather constructs a computational graph that is then executed without returning to the interpreter level. Tensorflow does support AVX and SSE (although not without pain), so you may expect more control over low-level details than with numpy. And you can also try to launch it on GPU.
7. Last thing, I don't quite believe in it, but does loop unrolling help?

---

```
for i in range(1, (T * n + 1) // 4):
        Y = Y + ...
        Y = Y + ...
        Y = Y + ...
        Y = Y + ...
```

---

* - subject to Amdahl's law

Comment: I will check out your answer later :). Thanks!